# Unique matching completion

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

Assume we have bridgeless cubic graph $G(V, E)$, $n=|V|$.
By [Petersen's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem), every such graph has a perfect matching. 
Moreover, given any edge in $G$ there exists a perfect matching containing this edge.
I am interested in finding the size $|C|$ of the smallest set of vertex-disjoint edges $C$ that uniquely determines a perfect matching $M$ (i.e. $C \subset M$).

Notice that every [cubic bridgeless graph](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870811001009) G has at least $ \Omega (2^{|V(G)|/3656})$ perfect matchings.

> What is the minimum number of vertex-disjoint edges $|C|$ that uniquely force any perfect matching in any bridgeless cubic graph?

Equivalently, a subset $C$ of a perfect matching $M$ is called a forcing set if $M$ is the unique perfect matching containing $C$. The forcing number of $M$ is the minimum cardinality of forcing sets of $M$. The forcing number of a cubic bridgeless graph $G(V, E)$ is the minimum number of forcing numbers of all perfect matchings of $G$. So my questions becomes:

> What is the forcing number for any bridgeless cubic graph?

I guess a constant is not enough. I guess that we need at least $|C|=\Omega( n)$ and $O(\log n)$ is not enough. Is there a proof?

Comment: I can understand this question in two ways: (1) what is the minimal $k$ such that in SOME (bridgeless cubic) graph there are $k$ edges uniquely defining a matching; or (2) what is the minimal $k$ such that in ANY (bridgeless cubic) graph there are $k$ edges uniquely defining a matching. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov The second one. I just edited the post.

Comment: It may be worth noting that in the first sense (1) of @IlyaBogdanov 's comment, the number  $k = 1$. An example is a circular ladder, where we modify one rung to "turn" it parallel to the ladder. (see Figure 1 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.2878.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Take a circular ladder of odd length. Also known as the cartesian product of $C_n$ ($n$ odd) and $K_2$. For every perfect matching there are many ways to change it into a different perfect matching by replacing two edges by another two (these four edges forming a 4-cycle).  I didn't work out the exact details, but it seems you can't specify one perfect matching exactly by giving less than about $\frac13 n$ edges, while there is one choice of about $\frac13 n$ edges that suffices. For even $n$, there is another type of perfect matching (not using any rungs) that can be uniquely specified by giving two edges.